# How to use NSOutlineView with ReactiveUI?

Tags: xamarin, monomac, reactiveui

I want to convert a small MonoMac application that I created so that it uses the MVVM pattern (especially to port in easily to Windows). I want to use the ReactiveUI framework. The current application uses an NSOutlineView control with a corresponding data source. As far as I could see there is no support currently for this control.

Is there a guideline how to adapt the NSOutlineView and data source so that it supports data binding as used by the ReactiveUI framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the data source support that ReactiveUI provides is iOS only and the code is quite complicated, but you can have a look at `ReactiveTableViewSource` and friends and try to create an equivalent for `NSOutlineViewDataSource`.

The general idea is, create a `NSOutlineViewDataSource` that can follow around a `ReactiveList` of ViewModels, and create Views for them as-needed.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I will have a look at ReactiveTableViewSource. Is there an overview what is currently supported for MonoMac or Xamarin.Mac by the framework?

Comment: @drvj: Did you get any solutions in the last 4 years? I am also trying to create an OutlineView, but the issue I am getting is how to pass ReactObject with a method that returns NSObject. Any help please.